# compact mongodb collection in background

Tags: database, mongodb, background-process, compact-database

I always run the compact command on mongodb and it disturb the performance of the DB , do you know if adding Background : true will work ? I'm asking before testing it .

```
db.runCommand({compact:'OPC_PLANT_DATA'}, {'background' : true})
```

Comment: Which version of MonogDB do you run?

Comment: MongoDB server version: 4.0.3

Comment: Then you may upgrade to latest version 4.4, see [compact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/index.html#behavior): *Starting in v4.4, on WiredTiger, compact only blocks the following metadata operations:

    db.collection.drop
    db.collection.createIndex and db.collection.createIndexes
    db.collection.dropIndex and db.collection.dropIndexes

compact does not block MongoDB CRUD Operations for the database it is currently operating on. Starting in v4.4, the compact command is appropriate for use at any time.*